# How i create image view with button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

[image]

I want create 32 views like above view. so that what i modify in my code so i get this view? I shown code below

```
 - (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 33;
[btnMenu setTag:0 ];
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            btnMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //NSData *data =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(, 1);
    [btnMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%d.jpg",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect frame = btnMenu.frame;
    frame.size.width=320;
    frame.size.height=420;
    frame.origin.x=0;
    frame.origin.y=0;
    btnMenu.frame=frame;
    [btnMenu setTag:i];
    btnMenu.alpha = 1;
    [btnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [awesomeView addSubview:btnMenu];

    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
    [awesomeView release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll release];}

-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
int whichButton = button.tag;
NSLog(@"Current TAG: %i", whichButton);
if(whichButton==1)
{
    first=[[FirstImage alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:first animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you want to do, if you want to add these 33 images as subview of scrollview, then you have to set the content size of scroll view accordingly and then in for loop set the frame of each image and them as subview of scroll view.

Comment: yes i want to add 32 views in each view image and a button will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

write this line in your code before the for loop.